# matrix and vector in same data package in R

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I am trying to learn a package named TropFishR by using the sample data provided by the package. The data provided by the package includes vectors and a matrix at the same time. How can I arrange my data like so

```
> data(alba)
> print(alba)
$sample.no
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14

$midLengths
 [1]  1.5  2.5  3.5  4.5  5.5  6.5  7.5  8.5  9.5 10.5 11.5 12.5 13.5 14.5

$dates
[1] "1976-04-17" "1976-07-02" "1976-09-19" "1976-12-15" "1977-02-18" "1977-
04-30"
[7] "1977-06-24"

$catch
  1976.29315068493 1976.50136986301 1976.71780821918 1976.95616438356 
  1977.13150684931
 [1,]                0                0                0                2                
0
 [2,]                0                1                9                1                
1
 [3,]                0                1               34                3                
0
 [4,]                1                0               96                3                
0
 [5,]                1                1               68                4                
2
 [6,]                1                0               50               21                

attr(,"class")
[1] "lfq"
```

Comment: can you please be more specific with your question, what is your objective?

Comment: To create a data including vectors and matrices like this.

Comment: do you need a dataframe? I am still not clear with exactly what you need

Comment: From @Md. Sahidul Islam its a list. Thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 1):

You can get idea from following code...

```
### Data generte.....
sample.no<-seq(1,14)
dates<-c("1976-04-17","1976-07-02","1976-09-19","1976-12-15","1977-02-18",
"1977-04-30","1977-06-24")

catch<-matrix(rbinom(25,20,0.5),5,5)
colnames(catch)<-c(10,20,30,40,50)


### Including within list named 'Yourdata'
Yourdata<-list(sample.no,dates,catch)
names(Yourdata)<-c("sample.no","dates","catch")
Yourdata
```

Output:

```
$sample.no
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14

$dates
[1] "1976-04-17" "1976-07-02" "1976-09-19" "1976-12-15" "1977-02-18"
[6] "1977-04-30" "1977-06-24"

$catch
     10 20 30 40 50
[1,] 11  8 11  8  9
[2,] 10 11 12  8  9
[3,]  9  8  8  8  9
[4,] 12 12 11 10 11
[5,] 11 10  9  9 15
```

Comment: That was what I was looking for. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Yahya as a gesture, please upvote and accept the answer